# League of Legends Low FPS on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, framerate

So I managed to get League of Legends install on my computer with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and I am getting 5-20 fps with lowest settings and resolution. I don't know what the issue is, Windows would run it at 60-80 FPS.

Anyone think they could help me?

EDIT: I've also heard that Wine "transfers" everything to OpenGL, could that be the case?

Comment: What graphics card and drivers are you running?

Comment: You could have said which CPU then...

Comment: Indeed. With Intel you're already using by default the Intel open source drivers. So, it won't be better than that. I suggest you check Wine for additional information: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=33303

Comment: @CelticWarrior I can't find anything there, is there no way to fix this?

Comment: It may not be fixable and it's not a Ubuntu question *per se*.